# Thoughts on "Existential Flourishing: A Phenomenology of the Virtues" by Irene McMullin?

Tags: existentialism, phenomenology, virtue-ethics

I recently came across a book titled "Existential Flourishing: A Phenomenology of the Virtues" by Irene McMullin and I'm considering purchasing it. Before I do, I wanted to reach out to the community here on Philosophy StackExchange to see if anyone has read this book and would be willing to share their thoughts and feedback.

I am particularly interested in understanding the content and ideas presented in the book. Does McMullin offer a unique perspective on existential flourishing and the virtues? How does she approach the subject from a phenomenological standpoint? Are her arguments well-supported and logically coherent?

Furthermore, I'm curious about the book's readability and accessibility. Is it written in a way that is engaging and easy to comprehend, or does it delve into complex jargon and difficult concepts that may require a deeper background in philosophy to fully grasp?

Any insights, critiques, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. I value the opinions and experiences of this community, and your input will help me make an informed decision before investing in this book.

If you haven't read "Existential Flourishing: A Phenomenology of the Virtues" but have come across other works by Irene McMullin, I would be interested to hear your thoughts on her writing style, scholarly contributions, and overall credibility as a philosopher.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to share your knowledge and experiences. I look forward to your responses and the opportunity to engage in a fruitful discussion.